# \overset and \implies not working right when combined

Tags: equations, symbols

I'm trying to make an implies arrow with an 'n' above it. I have no trouble with

```
$A \implies B$
$A \overset{n}{ \rightarrow } B$
```

but when I try to use

```
$A \overset{n}{ \implies } B$
```

I get the error:

```
! Argument of \UseTextAccent has an extra }.
<inserted text>
    \par
l.149 $A \overset{n}{\implies}
                              B$
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT

Here is a minimal example. It seems the issue is an interaction with the `tipa` package. If I comment that out, it works fine. Unfortunately I need to use them both.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tipa}

\begin{document}

$A \implies B$\\
$A \overset{n}{ \rightarrow } B$\\
$A \overset{n}{ \implies } B$\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. One way is to include the `amsmath` package *after* `tipa`:

   [image]
2. Loading `tipa` *after* `amsmath` results in errors

   > Command \; invalid in math mode

   The reason for this is that `tipa` redefines `\;` for its own purposes.
   So if your document needs *both* math and `tipa` functionality you have two options:

   a. Use `safe` mode: `\usepackage[safe]{tipa}` which disables these shortcuts.

   b. If your document heavily relies on these shortcuts, then you can disable those temporarily via `\tipasafemode`.

### Notes:

- As egreg pointed out `texdoc tipa` links to the German version of the documentation, but `texdoc timpaman` provides the English version.

---

### Code: Load `amsmath` *after* `tipa`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$A \implies B$

$A \overset{n}{ \rightarrow } B$

$A \overset{n}{ \implies } B$

\end{document}
```

---

### Code: `safe` mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[safe]{tipa}

\begin{document}

$A \implies B$

$A \overset{n}{ \rightarrow } B$

$A \overset{n}{ \implies } B$

\end{document}
```

---

### Code: Use `\tipasafemode` as needed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tipa}

\begin{document}

$\tipasafemode A \implies B$

$\tipasafemode A \overset{n}{ \rightarrow } B$

$\tipasafemode A \overset{n}{ \implies } B$

\end{document}
```

Comment: That solved the \implies problem, but broke my Greek symbols. See new edit above. :(

Comment: Oh wait! That was stupid...\Beta isn't a symbol. That was a totally different issue because it should have been \beta. Thanks again for helping me work through this.

Comment: For strange reasons, `texdoc tipa` points to the German documentation. However, `texdoc tipaman` will open the English version of the manual.